# Text cut off in jquery mobile list view

Tags: jquery, android, mobile

Why does the (ul > li) not expand for the data as a default?

What style can I add to that (li) so the text isn't cut off. This is a read-only list.

### Content showing in the following format:

```
Eg: Hello world...
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks,
Vishnu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a few weeks ago:

```
.ui-li .ui-btn-text a.ui-link-inherit { /* This are the added classes from jQuery mobile */
    white-space: normal;                /* And this enables more than one line */
}
```